# Using GNU ld, how can I force the address of a specific (external) symbol without getting a "relocation truncated" error?

Tags: mips, linker-errors, ld, relocation, linker-scripts

I have two functions, `a()` and `b()`, that both have specific, fixed **load/run-time** addresses. I am compiling `a()` myself, while `b()` is already provided (e.g. in ROM).

The file `a.c` is as follows:

```
extern void b(void);

void a(void) {
    b();
}
```

This generates the following assembly code:

```
00000000 <a>:
   0:   08000000       j 0 <a>
                       0: R_MIPS_26 b
   4:   00000000       nop
```

So it's putting a 26-bit relocation to `b()` there (the target of the call is a 26-bit offset from the address of the call instruction itself). Let's say the specific addresses of `a` and `b` are 0x80001000 and 0x80002000, respectively. That should be fine; `b` is easily within reach of `a`.

So in my linker script, I have something like this:

```
SECTIONS {
    a = 0x80001000;
    b = 0x80002000;

    .text : AT(0x80000000) {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

However, linking `a.o` with this script gives me the following error:

```
a.o: In function 'a':
(.text+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_26 against `b`
```

Presumably, this is because the linker is trying to fit the full 32-bit value (`0x80002000`) into the 26-bit space for the target of the jump. What's wrong with my linker script?

Comment: For reference, this seems relevant: http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-06/msg00132.html

Comment: I can't help with the linker script, but an alternative solution would be to use function pointers. For just a couple of functions that wouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Have you tried using `b=0x2000` in the script? That's the value that the linker needs to insert into the `J` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `long_call` attribute:

```
__attribute__((long_call))
extern void b(void);
```

Manual for all MIPS attributes is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Function-Attributes.html).